# Streaming images over QTcpSocket on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt, tcp, streaming

I am trying to create two test applications based on QTcpSocket, a server that streams (uncompressed) images and a client that receives them.

My code is mostly taken from Qts [Fortune Client Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneclient.html)  and [Fortune Server Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html). I have cut out all gui. Instead of opening a connection, sending a fortune and then immediately closing it, my server keeps it open and continuously streams my image. The client just reads the images from the QTcpSocket and then discards them.

The image I'm sending is 800x600 RGB (=1440000 bytes), I am sending it as often as I am allowed. The image is read from file each time before it is sent and I am not using any compression.

The server seems to be sending images just as it should. BUT the client receives them too slowly, 1-4 frames per second, and it seems to not be receiving any data at times, which in turn causes my server to use alot of memory (because the client isn't reading as fast as the server is writing).

I've tried running my server and client on different machines and both on one machine, both setups produce the same problem.

When running my applications on a Linux machine, the client receives images at a much higher rate (think it was 14 frames per second). The client seems to be able to read as fast as the server writes.

Can anyone help shed some light on this problem?

1. How can I speed up the data transfere? (without using compression)
2. How can I get the client to read as fast as the server is writing?
3. How can I get this to be stable on my Windows machine? (no sudden pauses...) Clicking in the console window of the client sometimes seem to "wake" the application btw. ^^

Here is my code:

Server:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "Server.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QString ipaddress = QString(argv[1]);
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);
    Server* server = new Server(ipaddress, port);
    int retVal = app.exec();
    return retVal;
}
```

Server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

#include <QObject>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QTcpServer;
class QNetworkSession;
class QTcpSocket;
class QTimer;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Server : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Server(QString ipAddress, int port, QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void newConnectionSlot();
    void sendSlot();

private:
    QTcpServer          *mTcpServer;
    QTcpSocket          *mTcpSocket;
    QTimer              *mSendTimer;
};

#endif /* SERVER_H_ */
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QSettings>
#include <highgui.h>

Server::Server(QString ipAddress, int port, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), mTcpServer(0), mTcpSocket(0)
{
    mTcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(mTcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnectionSlot()));
    if (!mTcpServer->listen(QHostAddress(ipAddress), port)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to start the server: " << mTcpServer->errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "The server is running on\n\nIP: "<< ipAddress.toStdString()
            << "\nport: " << mTcpServer->serverPort() << "\n\nRun the Client now.\n" << std::endl;
}

void Server::newConnectionSlot()
{
    mTcpSocket = mTcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),
            mTcpSocket, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    // setup timer to send data at a given interval
    mSendTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(mSendTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
            this, SLOT(sendSlot()));
    mSendTimer->start(40);
}

void Server::sendSlot()
{
    if(!mTcpSocket)
        return;

    //know that the image is this big
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    int nChannels = 3;
    int depth = 8;
    qint64 blockSize = 1440000; //in bytes

    qint64 imagesInQue = mTcpSocket->bytesToWrite()/blockSize;
    int maxPendingImages = 25;
    if(imagesInQue > maxPendingImages)
    {
        std::cout << "Dumping." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    //load image
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("pic1_24bit.bmp");
    if(!img)
        std::cout << "Error loading image " << std::endl;;

    //send data
    quint64 written = mTcpSocket->write(img->imageData, img->imageSize);

    //clean up
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
}
```

Client:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "Client.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QString ipaddress = QString(argv[1]);
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);
    Client* client = new Client(ipaddress, port);
    int retVal = app.exec();
}
```

Client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractSocket>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QTcpSocket;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Client(QString ipAddress, int port, QObject *parent=0);

private slots:
    void readSlot();
    void displayErrorSlot(QAbstractSocket::SocketError);

private:
    QTcpSocket          *mTcpSocket;
    QString             mIpAddress;
    int                 mPort;
};

#endif /* CLIENT_H_ */
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDateTime>

Client::Client(QString ipAddress, int port, QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent), mTcpSocket(0), mIpAddress(ipAddress), mPort(port)
{
    mTcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(readSlot()));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(displayErrorSlot(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    std::cout << "Connecting to ip: " << mIpAddress.toStdString() << " port: " << mPort << std::endl;
    mTcpSocket->connectToHost(mIpAddress, mPort);
}

void Client::readSlot()
{
    static qint64 starttime = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    static int frames = 0;

    //know that the image is this big
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    int nChannels = 3;
    int depth = 8;
    qint64 blockSize = 1440000; //in bytes

    if (mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
    {
        return;
    }
    frames++;

    char* data = (char*) malloc(blockSize+100);
    qint64 bytesRead = mTcpSocket->read(data, blockSize);

    free(data);

    //FPS
    if(frames % 100 == 0){
        float fps = frames/(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - starttime);
        std::cout << "FPS: " << fps << std::endl;
    }
}

void Client::displayErrorSlot(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{
    switch (socketError) {
    case QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError:
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError:
        std::cout << "The host was not found. Please check the "
                                    "host name and port settings."<< std::endl;
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError:
        std::cout << "The connection was refused by the peer. "
                                    "Make sure the fortune server is running, "
                                    "and check that the host name and port "
                                    "settings are correct."<< std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "The following error occurred: " << mTcpSocket->errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running both server and client programs on the same computer or over a network? If over network, what speed is that network? Is the server or client computer doing lots of other network activity?

Comment: I've tried running them both on the same computer and over a network, both setups give the same result. There was not a lot of network activity when running over the network. Kinda strange that both setups give the same result, right? And why does this work on Linux? Is it the Qt implementation of the Tcp socket?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are miscounting your frames. You must increment the frame counter after the `mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < blockSize` test! That's the source of your non-problem: it works OK, but you miscount the frames. That's also why it "works better" on Linux: the network stack there is buffering the data differently, giving you less signals.
2. You must limit the amount of memory *on the wire* (buffered) on the server end. Otherwise, as you correctly noticed, you'll run out of memory. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979106/1329652) for an example of how to do it.
3. You're never freeing the memory you `malloc()` in the receiver. Be aware that you should expect to consume 35 megabytes of RAM per second if the server really sends at 40ms intervals. The receiver may well get bogged down very quickly by that memory leak. That's probably the source of the trouble.
4. What is that `QDataStream` for? You're not using a datastream to send the image, and there's no use for it on the receiving end either.

Comment: 1. I agree on that. The thing is that this is a simple example I made to try to find the problem in my other (much larger and more complex) application, there I had a scheme for limiting the buffer on the server side. I will update my example code. <br/>2. I corrected that blunder, thanks. <br/> 3. QDataStream is not used for anything, forgot to delete it, fixed now. <br/>

Comment: True, I fixed that now. Frames are now counted correctly, which gives me 0 fps. :P But I still have a problem, because this actually works better on linux. In my complex application I am streaming images that are shown live on the server, on Linux the video is actually live, while on Windows, the video freezes and starts dumping frames.

Comment: Yeah, got me on that one, the frames were counted optimistically, duh :) I'll check it out after work and see why it's behaving that way. It shouldn't.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `std::endl` console flush takes very long. Could you put the `//FPS` block inside a `if (frame % 100 == 0) {...}` test and see if that helps?

Comment: Just tested it (and edited the code), and it does not help at all. :( Server is dumping almost constantly and the clients fps is 0. Writes to console every 4 seconds or so.

Comment: I suggest getting rid of all the networkmanager junk. It's only useful on mobile devices, and doesn't really make any sense in a simple test case. Just rip it out. Maybe that's where the problem is, somehow. You only need to use QTcpSocket in the client, on a hardcoded address and port. You should always keep pruning until the essence is left. You should have perhaps 30-40 lines of code left. Keep it simple. That's why creating the simplest test case often helps in isolating the issue. Oftentimes it's not where you'd think it is.

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up the code as you suggested, but it didn't help sadly. Could the issues I experience be due to the different implementations of QTcpSocket on Windows and Linux? Starting to get a bit desperate here, might have to try a different tcp implementation soon. :/